# Parse Full Name Into Parts

Tags: excel, vba, parsing

I have a list of full names that may not include a middle name, middle initial, and suffix.

I want to parse the name into the appropriate, separate columns, as seen below. (The suffix could include Jr, Jr., Sr, Sr., II, III, IV and V... for now.)

The closest I've come is this code: (where `emptyRow` has been determined as the first available row without data)

```vb
Dim MyText As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim MyResult() As String
  
MyText = Range("A" & emptyRow).Value
MyResult = Split(MyText)

For i = 0 To UBound(MyResult)
    Cells(emptyRow, i).Value = MyResult(i)
Next I
```

But, it doesn't do anything about missing items, like middle name, or suffix.

| (A1)Full Name | (B1)First Name | (C1)Middle Name | (D1)Last Name | (E1)Suffix |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Adam Doe Jr. | John | Adam | Doe | Jr. |
| John A Doe Jr | John | A | Doe | Jr |
| John Doe Jr | John |  | Doe | Jr |
| John Adam Doe | John | Adam | Doe |  |
| John A Doe | John | A | Doe |  |
| John Doe | John |  | Doe |  |

UPDATE:

Here's what I came up with. I think it works.

```vb
MyResult = Split(MyText)
i = UBound(MyResult)
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = MyResult(0)
If MyResult(i) = "Jr." Or MyResult(i) = "Jr" Or MyResult(i) = "Sr." Or MyResult(i) = "Sr" Or MyResult(i) = "II" Or MyResult(i) = "ii" Or MyResult(i) = "III" Or MyResult(i) = "IIi" Or MyResult(i) = "Iii" Or MyResult(i) = "IiI" Or MyResult(i) = "iii" Or MyResult(i) = "iIi" Or MyResult(i) = "iiI" Or MyResult(i) = "iII" Or MyResult(i) = "iI" Or MyResult(i) = "Ii" Or MyResult(i) = "IV" Or MyResult(i) = "V" Or MyResult(i) = "iv" Or MyResult(i) = "v" Or MyResult(i) = "Iv" Or MyResult(i) = "iV" Then
    If i = 5 Then
        Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = MyResult(i)
        Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = MyResult(3) & " " & MyResult(4)
        Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = MyResult(1) & " " & MyResult(2)
        ElseIf i = 4 Then
            Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = MyResult(i)
            Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = MyResult(2) & " " & MyResult(3)
            Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = MyResult(1)
        ElseIf i = 3 Then
            Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = MyResult(i)
            Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = MyResult(2)
            Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = MyResult(1)
        Else
            Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = MyResult(i)
            Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = MyResult(1)
    End If
    ElseIf i = 4 Then
        Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = MyResult(3) & " " & MyResult(4)
        Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = MyResult(1) & " " & MyResult(2)
        ElseIf i = 3 Then
            Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = MyResult(2) & " " & MyResult(3)
            Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = MyResult(1)
        ElseIf i = 2 Then
            Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = MyResult(2)
            Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = MyResult(1)
        Else
            Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = MyResult(1)
End If
```

Comment: How is the code supposed to see a difference between the middle name and the last name?

Comment: This requires the same type of logic you would use when doing this manually.  Only two parts to the text  = first + last name.  More then two parts and the last part is in your list of suffixes = last part is the suffix, then divide up the other parts accordingly.  Etc etc.  There's no 100% one-liner for this - you need to come up with some rules, and then implement those rules in your code.

Comment: To build on what Tim said, the hardest part will be multi-word last names.  Eg why is `Doe Smith` a last name and not `Adam Doe` ?  Do you have some rules for that?

Comment: Agree how is it supposed to tell the difference between a middle name and a combined last name? The rest is fairly easy to do but that part is basically impossible unless you have some rules/list of potentials etc.

Comment: @Simon, chris, Tim, chrisneilsen - Those are all the questions/problems that I was running into with this situation. How about this: 1)Remove the suffix, if exists 2)Count the number of "words" remaining 3)If "words" > 2, then assume the 2nd one is a middle name, else just have FName, LName 4)Place name components in respective cells ~~~ How would something like THAT look in VBA? (I'll edit the original post as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my take on it. I included the choice of using extra names into either the middle or last name. It's quickly made and rather basic method and I'm sure there are various ways it could be improved but it works well regardless.

Have a go with it. Just set and change the necessary parts.

```
Sub ExtractName()

Dim ws As Worksheet, lRow As Long, i As Long, SplitName, IsSuffix As Boolean
Dim LastNamePos As Integer, j As Integer, SplitLast As Integer, LastStart As Integer

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Change column as needed

With ws
    For i = 2 To lRow 'change starting row if needed
        SplitName = Split(.Range("A" & i), " ")
        SplitLast = UBound(SplitName)
        Select Case SplitName(SplitLast)
            Case "Jr", "Jr.", "Sr", "Sr.", "II", "III", "IV", "V"
                .Range("E" & i) = SplitName(SplitLast) 'Add Suffix to column
                IsSuffix = True
            Case Else
                IsSuffix = False
        End Select
        .Range("B" & i) = SplitName(0) 'Add first name to column

        If IsSuffix = True Then
            LastNamePos = 1
        Else
            LastNamePos = 0
        End If
        '---------------------- Extra names go to middle name
        .Range("D" & i) = SplitName(SplitLast - LastNamePos) 'Add last name to column
        For j = 1 To SplitLast - LastNamePos - 1 'Add middle names to column
            If .Range("C" & i) = "" Then
                .Range("C" & i) = SplitName(j)
            Else
                .Range("C" & i) = .Range("C" & i) & " " & SplitName(j)
            End If
        Next j
        '---------------------- Extra names go to last name
'        If IsSuffix = True And SplitLast >= 3 Then
'            .Range("C" & i) = SplitName(1)
'            LastStart = 2
'        ElseIf IsSuffix = False And SplitLast >= 2 Then
'            .Range("C" & i) = SplitName(1)
'            LastStart = 2
'        Else
'            LastStart = 1
'        End If
'        For j = LastStart To SplitLast - LastNamePos
'            If .Range("D" & i) = "" Then
'                .Range("D" & i) = SplitName(j)
'            Else
'                .Range("D" & i) = .Range("D" & i) & " " & SplitName(j)
'            End If
'        Next j
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I JUST saw your post after I submitted my update. Thanks so much for helping. I genuinely appreciate it!